# Joomla extension Sourcerer conflict with gantry / rocket theme

Tags: joomla3.0

Anyone else run into a conflict between sourcerer and a Rocket Theme template on Gantry? The sourcerer code works in an article but not in a module (it just shows the {tag}code{/tag}). I tried to find a way to ask this on Rocket Theme's site but I don't think I've paid them enough $ to get to ask a question :-<

In particular, I'm using the Vermilion template (on Joomla 3.2.4) which has some pretty sophisticated modules so I'm thinking there's something going on to undo the sourcerer code. I think it's the latest gantry version. BTW I'm not using any of the really complex modules. Just 'custom html' type in one of the theme's positions but no joy.

Anyway I thought somebody might have run into this or something similar and could point me in the right direction. Thanks -

Comment: could you post come code where you suspect this error either the template, gantry or sourcerer's code?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that I thought might be conflicting. It's been a while since I was into the code but when I get a chance I'll revisit. I just did something else on this project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sourcerer works fine for me with Gantry templates on Joomla 3.x.

Edit your Custom HTML module, go to the Options tab and check that you have "Prepare Content" set to "Yes".

Comment: Thanks Neil. The option is set to Yes. Sorry it took so long to respond. This is a volunteer project and I had to work for a few weeks so back burnered it. I did a work around so will live with it for now, but if anyone happens by with a suggestion, I'd appreciate it.